# Spring form option does not select item, options does

Tags: spring

`${products}` contains a `List<Product>`. `Product` is a `@Entity`, has an `equals` method that compares by `id`. There is no converter or formatter registered for `Product` (other than Spring Data's `DomainClassConverter` but that doesn't seem to kick in for this case):

This works:

```
<form:select path="productFrom">
     <form:option value="" label="-" />
     <form:options items="${products}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

This (needed for optgroup-ing, but simplified here) does not select the correct value:

```
<form:select path="productFrom">
     <form:option value="" label="-" />
     <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
         <form:option value="${product.id}">${product.name}</form:option>
     </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

After debugging `SelectedValueComparator` I found that it tries to compare a `candidateValue` of type `Long` to a `boundValue` of `String`. I could work this around by creating a `toString()` method in product that returns the `id` as `String`. (Or I could have modified the `equals()` method to handle `Long`.)

Still, I have a bad feeling that I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by adding a new method to `Product`:

```
public String getIdString() {
    return id == null ? "" : id.toString();
}
```

and changing the option definition:

```
<form:option value="${product.idString}">${product.name}</form:option>
```

Still not sure I'm doing this the right way, any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Talking to myself again, unfortunately, accepting my own answer then... sigh